# Calculation of sample size for given width of confidence interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, sample-size

Can someone explain to me how they got to the answer here? The way I answered it was 1.96(4/SQRT(n))=4 which then gave me 3.8416. I'm just confused on how he got to 2 as his SQRT(N). My guess would've been that he took the SQRT(4) but it makes no sense why he would then do 1.96(4/2)^2 as the final equation.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There isn't any step here where "he got to $2$ as his $\sqrt{n}.$"  Have you noticed that $z(\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ is *half* the width of the confidence interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem asks for the sample size required so that the confindence interval has width 4. The interval is symmetric around $\mu$, and the distance from $\mu$ to each edge of the interval is $1.96\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$
The total width is therefore two times this. So, to make the confidence interval have width 4, $n$ must satisfy the equation
$1.96\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \frac{4}{2}.$